# Having a problem with the width of a zoomable image element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, ionic-framework

I made an **image viewer** component to pinch-zoom in its mobile app using **react** **ionic**. My problem is that when I zoom the image, it will be zoomed just to the image's width. I want the image to be zoomed to the edge of the card padding.
here are my codes

```
<React.Fragment>
  <IonCard id="ImgViewCard">
    <IonCardContent>
      <TransformWrapper>
        <TransformComponent>
          <IonImg id="ImgViewImage" src={prop.ImgSource}></IonImg>
        </TransformComponent>
      </TransformWrapper>
    </IonCardContent>
  </IonCard>
</React.Fragment>;
```

```
#ImgViewCard {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#ImgViewImage {
  height: 370px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the image in a container using the full width of the container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-card">
      <img src="">
</div>
</div>
```

.image-card

```
.image-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
}
```

I think this will help.